# Ionic Serve Live Reload Not Working

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, reload, live, serve

I just bought a new MacBook and installed ionic/cordova on my machine, but alas "ionic serve" no longer live reloads HTML changes. Specifically, I see it reloading, but once the reload is complete, the changes are not reflected. Curiously, changes to *.ts reload fine! Any ideas? I'm a newbie but having to stop/start the server each time for every little change is driving me crazy - thank you!

```
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.5
Ionic Native: 2.4.1
Ionic App Scripts: 1.0.1
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 7.5.0
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Here's what I see on terminal:

```
[23:10:04]  build started ... 
[23:10:04]  transpile started ... 
[23:10:08]  transpile finished in 3.93 s 
[23:10:08]  webpack update started ... 
[23:10:09]  webpack update finished in 524 ms 
[23:10:09]  build finished in 4.46 s
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic serve not working in Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448366/ionic-serve-not-working-in-ionic-3)

Comment: It is not a dupe. That question is about reload not detecting file changes - in this one, reload does detect file changes and reloads, but the changes aren't reflected.

Comment: I have this same problem - you don't have to restart ionic serve every time, you can just hit "refresh" on the browser after it's finished refreshing (which is annoying, but less annoying).

Comment: I suggest upgrading to the latest Ionic version, `3.9.2`. I remember having this problem with older versions of Ionic, but I don't have it anymore. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/v3/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Update tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 5):

**Dev environment:**

- Node   - v10.17.0
- Npm    - v6.11.3
- ionic  - v5.4.5

**I resolved this issue as follows:**

- Updated ionic: `npm i -g ionic` (went from 5.4.5 to 5.4.6)
- Ran `ionic repair`

Comment: ionic repair did the job for me. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Update ***tsconfig.json*** file

```
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "compilerOptions": {
    "watch": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, I was having the same issues, until I figured out that everytime that you make a change you have to wait until it get fully reloaded, if you make multiples changes the time until building and deploying to `ionic serve` starts to get very slow.

Resuming, my solution was to wait until the very end so I could see that it was successfully deployed to the `ionic serve`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be my issue as I've tried it with minor changes and it won't reload (or rather, re-render) HTML changes. It DOES however reload/render changes to SCSS or TS perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

remove node_module folder and
run: "npm install"
after that try "ionic serve"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a new project, then just copy the files with the source code into this new project.

Create new project

```
$ ionic start App5-WishList tabs
```

Run server

```
$ ionic serve
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$ cd ProjectFolder
$ ionic serve
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/

Comment: I'm not new to ionic serve - my problem is that for some reason, changes to html files do not render after the live reload. Changes to SCSS and TS reload/render perfectly fine. Any ideas?