# Ionic serve not working in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-cli

My Ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
Cordova Platforms  : browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

Node : v6.9.0
npm  : 3.10.8 
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Ionic serve is working fine, but does not detect any file changes!

The problem appears only for Ionic v3 and v2 projects.

My Ionic v1 projects are working fine.

Comment: always or after a while?

Comment: Ionic serve work fine! after that not detect any changes,

Comment: Have you updated the ionic global package? if not try ( npm update -g ionic)

Comment: yes it is updated to latest version but not working

Comment: Try adding --livereload to command.

Comment: can you try with --liverload (ionic serve --liverload).

Answer (score 3):

For update changes in platform file you have to run **ionic cordova prepare** and then run **ionic serve** it works..
**ionic cordova prepare** copy all files of **www** into **platform** directory that will reflect in your apk or ipa

Comment: no change after executing **Ionic cordova prepare**

Comment: one more thing please check node version and npm version as well, you have to update it as well because it will download maven repo. according to that

Comment: node version 6.9.0 npm 5.2.0. is it needed to update? npm is updated!

Comment: Ionic is working on maven repository in background, you have to make sure after updating ionic and node version it update repository into .gradle directory.

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: if you are uses command line, once you add platform you can see that screen it down loads some data from maven.gradle.com

Answer (score 3):

When I use ionic cli build app(ionic3 + angular5),same problem happened to me.I updated '@ionic/app-scripts' to version '3.1.6',then problem solved

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

`ionic serve --verbose` =>didn’t work, there were errors;

`npm run ionic:build --verbose` =>ran, finnished with OK.

Comment: it's work fine now! it is permission problem while running `sudo ionic serve` it worked for me

Comment: glad  to help you , any issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use "npm install" and then "gulp build" & "gulp serve". Also make sure you update all the dependencies. Check versions of your dependencies by "ionic info".

Comment: showing no gulp file found after installing gulp using **npm install gulp**

Answer (score 1):

Try ***npm run ionic:serve***. Similar issue occurred when installing the latest cordova update.

Comment: Sorry! no use using **npm run ionic:serve**

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps.. May be it will help

```
npm install -g ionic@latest

npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

npm install ionic-angular@latest --save

ionic serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use these commands in your project.

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288

sudo sysctl -p --system
```

And again run ionic serve

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and then use the command

```
npm install
```

followed by

```
ionic serve--verbose
```

Hope that it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

i faced this problem before ,try this instead of ionic serve :

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "sudo" with any of the ionic/npm commands. If it throws error without "sudo", then you can fix it by changing the owner of the npm packages, using the command below:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

Answer (score 0):

my configurations for running ionic 3 application:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.2.1
npm               : 5.5.0 
OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /root/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands in your prompt.

```
npm cache clear --force
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Install ws:

```
npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 3 you have to type:

- `cordova run android` or `cordova run ios`, to deploy your build in
  device.
- `cordova build android` or `cordova build ios`, for build only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this cmd

npm run ionic:serve

Answer (score 0):

I think your prob is the

```
NODE version (6.9.1) ..
```

can you just try to upgrade to 9.1.0 or more?

Answer (score 0):

My answers works. My machine is also having a different package of Node which I forgot about in the first place.

So I've removed node_modules using:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.
```

To make things less complicated with all cli - head up back https://nodejs.org/ and install back the LTS package

Uninstall Node from brew
**re-install node.js using conventional way using the installer**

Answer (score 0):

Include below script in the package.json file

```
"browser": "ionic-app-scripts serve --sourceMap source-map --iscordovaserve --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build"
and run
```

After It Run `npm run browser`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such a problem, tried a fresh new app, worked perfectly, tried another old app, also worked perfectly.

Tried to stop using some modules (clipboard in my case and another one), solved the problem, in my case it was an error in the way I am importing or using it.

ionic 5 is my ionic version

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

What Worked for me was repairing the project `ionic repair` , then I ran `ionic serve` and it worked fine. Hope this solves your problem.